# AMSv3 Multiple track files as inputs to an Asset

Tags: azure-media-services

Goal: Use a single streaming locator to several tracks of mp3s where the client can get one token with the streaming locator's claim and play each track during its lifetime.

I modified my output asset job process to use the `List<string> files`, but the job fails saying the input asset does not have a primary file.

Is my approach wrong, or is there a way to say `track1.mp3` is the primary?

I am trying to configure a situation like this:

- 1 stream locator (1 claim required for access)
- several tracks in that locator (`1.mp3, 2.mp3, ... 50.mp3`)
- customer buys 1 sku, gets that stream locator's claim

This would be my expected approach.  However, my fallback (and fear) is that AMS wants me to have a `1:1` with `1.mp3:streamlocator.contentkey.id` and maintain that list in a backend, then use this sequence flow:

1. Client requests token from a lookup endpoint
2. Endpoint compares their ownership vs the requested `1.mp3`
3. If they have access to the sku `1.mp3` belongs to in the backend, issue signed token with the the content key id associated from `1.mp3:streamlocator.contentkey.id`
4. If they dont have access, 401 the token request back the client app to handle

Comment: Two aspects here - one about using a single streaming locator for many tracks, and the second about the job failing. I'll ask colleagues to weigh in on the former, but the v3 APIs currently do not support taking a list of MP3 files as input to a Job.

Comment: Appreciate it, I was exploring if its possible after reading this (the `string[] files` in particular): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/jobs/create#jobinputasset

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a step back and modify the scenario a bit: suppose it is a (single bitrate or multi-bitrate) video with 3 audio streams. And you want a 1:1 mapping for streaming_locator : content_key_id : media_asset. With a token containing the right claims you can get the decryption key/license and play any of the 3 audio streams (with video) with a video player. This scenario is supported by AMS and I don't see any problem with this.

However, your scenario is MP3 (without video). My concern is whether there is a binding between MP3 and AES-128 encryption or any DRM, and using such binding in AMS dynamic packaging. Without such encryption, how do you enforce the protection or what is the purpose of token?

Comment: A sku for an "album" of 1..n tracks, where each the content key id can be associated to the sku in terms of backend lookup for token issuance.  Right now, it works with 1:1 key:mp3.  But that also means in the backend, if a customer buys a SKU, they can have `..n` possible claims to issue in a stream token to AMS.  This is more of a maintainability and purchase fulfillment options that can work with AMSv3's expected configuration.

Comment: Thomas, may I ask which encryption do you use for MP3, AES?

Comment: No `cenc` widevine and playready, Server side held HS256 signing on JWT delivery for the content key id claim

Comment: In that case, suppose 1.mp3, 2.mp3 and 3.mp3 are in the same asset. With the single locator, and the single token, you can get to stream any of the 3 MP3 file like https://host/locator_id/[i].mp3, right? And the single token allows you to get a single DRM license which can be used to decrypt any of the encrypted MP3 which are in the same asset, using a single content key.

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to do.  In my post, I mention the job fails with the error message "input asset does not have a primary file".

Comment: By "primary file", it means the .ism file, an xml file indicating audio, video tracks, etc. AMS dynamic packager uses it to package contents for streaming. For regular video/audio asset, that is clear, but for MP3 files, I don't know what its .ism file look like. Is this event supported by dynamic packager?